# How can I find which URLs were recently de-indexed in Google Web Master Tools/Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

When checking the Index Status for my site in Google Webmaster Tools/Search Console, I saw that the total indexed URLs in the previous day was 670. However today it is 655 (I can see this in the graph). So 15 URLs were de-indexed.

How can I find which URLs were de-indexed?

Comment: Google is building this feature for Search Console and they have made it available in the invite-only beta.  I can see this data for one of my sites which was invited to the beta.

Comment: See also: [Determining which sitemap entries not indexed by google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32208/determining-which-sitemap-entries-not-indexed-by-google)

Comment: [How can I find out what pages of my site are not indexed by Googlebot?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60951/how-can-i-find-out-what-pages-of-my-site-are-not-indexed-by-googlebot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have an access to the news search console:

- On the left you go to your sitemaps.
- Then you click on your sitemap, the url is https://search.google.com/u/1/search-console/sitemaps/info-drilldown?resource_id=http://example.com&sitemap=http://example.com/sitemap.xml
- And then you click on "see index coverage".

On this page you will see the situation with your sitemap (not with the whole site): indexed, not indexed urls, and why is what happens.